# How to get the return from Axios.get and Render components dynamically on a Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I have a Functional Component and I am trying to get data from an `axios.get()` and render some components dynamically based on the response of the request.

If I `console.log` the response is `Ok`, but my problem is how to use the return from `axios.get()` to create components on the screen.

I've tried with a simple array and using it I can create the components. What I want is to create the components on screen the same way I've done with the array.

I've read a lot of post before posting my own. I would really appreciate some help or guidance.

```js
import React, { createElement, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity, Image } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  axios.get("http://100.103.16.113:8081/api/checklists", {
  }).then
    (function (response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    })
  const checklists = [{
    "id": 1,
    "checklisT_DESCRIPTION": "CHECKLIST 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "checklisT_DESCRIPTION": "CHECKLIST 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "checklisT_DESCRIPTION": "CHECKLIST 3"
  }
  ]
  return (
    <View >
      <Text style={styles.text}> Select an Audit</Text>

      <View style={styles.maincontainer}>
        <View style={styles.container}>

          {}
          {checklists.map(r => (

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('AuditS')} style={styles.button}
            >
              <Image source={require('../assets/icons8-audit-80.png')} style={styles.Image}></Image>
              <Text style={styles.ButtonText}>{r.checklisT_DESCRIPTION}</Text>

            </TouchableOpacity >
          ))}

        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.bottomcontainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Login')}
        >
          <Text style={styles.logout}>LOGOUT</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 50,
    fontFamily: 'Comfortaa-Regular',
    alignItems: "center",
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    textAlign: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  container: {
    marginTop: 50,
    flexDirection: "row",
    marginLeft: 50,
    width: '100%'
  },
  maincontainer: {
    flexDirection: "column",
    width: '80%',
    alignContent: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  bottomcontainer: {
    marginTop: '70%',
    width: '100%',
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "flex-end",
    alignContent: "flex-end",
  },
  logout: {
    marginTop: 50,
    margin: 15,
    height: 60,
    width: 440,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    backgroundColor: '#000000',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: "center",
    textAlignVertical: "center",
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    fontFamily: 'Comfortaa-Bold'
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#0f99f5',
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#FFF',
    width: 150,
    height: 150,
    borderRadius: 10,
    textAlignVertical: "bottom",
    textAlign: "center",
    marginVertical: 20,
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    fontFamily: 'Comfortaa-Bold'
  },
  ButtonText: {
    textAlignVertical: "bottom",
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#FFF',
    marginHorizontal: 10,
    fontFamily: 'Comfortaa-Bold'
  },
  Image: {
    width: "50%",
    height: "50%",
    alignContent: "center",
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: 10,
    marginBottom: 10
  }
});

export default HomeScreen;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a state variable for `checklists` then populate it using `axios.get` inside an `useEffect`. Make sure you verify if the checklist is populated or not by checking `checklists.length` before mapping over the list and accessing the data to render items.

```js
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  // initialize the state variable
  const [checklists, setChecklists] = useState([]);


  // populate the data
  useEffect(() => {
   axios.get("http://100.103.16.113:8081/api/checklists")
         .then(function (response) {
                 setChecklists(response.data)
              })
         .catch(error => {
                 console.log(error);                        
         })
  }, [])

  // when mapping over the checklists make sure you check for the checklists.length before mapping

  {checklists.length &&  checklists.map(r =>(

      <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => navigation.navigate('AuditS')} 
         style={styles.button}    
      >
        <Image source={require('../assets/icons8-audit-80.png')} 
          style={styles.Image}>
        </Image>     
        <Text style={styles.ButtonText}>{r.checklisT_DESCRIPTION}</Text>

      </TouchableOpacity >
       ))}

}
```

Here is an example [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-kym1l?file=/App.js)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comments on the code, I changed my code according to your orientations and it's working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a state inside the component.

```js
import React, { createElement, useState, useEffect  } from 'react';


const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

  const [checkList, setCheckList] = useState([{
                "id": 1,
                "checklisT_DESCRIPTION": "CHECKLIST 1"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "checklisT_DESCRIPTION": "CHECKLIST 2"
              },
              {
                "id": 3,
                "checklisT_DESCRIPTION": "CHECKLIST 3"
              }
            ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://100.103.16.113:8081/api/checklists", {      
                  }).then
                   (function (response) {
                    setCheckList(response.data); // update the state
                  }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);                        
                  })
  }, [])

  return (
```

Answer (score 2):

You simply need to save the callback in a state, something like:

```
...

const [checklist, setChecklist] = React.useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
axios.get("http://100.103.16.113:8081/api/checklists", {})
  .then
    (function (response) {
      setChecklist(response?.data);
    console.log(response.data);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);                        
  })
}, []);
...
```

To avoid null pointer exceptions, I suggest you use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and block rendering until the promise has been resolved.

Comment: @VinodSai Yes, well punctuated. I ended up being too shallow in my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the additional link.